# PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied on CSS file - Python Flask

Tags: python, flask

I apologize if this very specific scenario has been answered on another question, I have tried  fixes proposed on several similar questions, but nothing seems to work.

When trying to run my Flask (Python 3.8.2) app I keep getting the following error on an specific CSS file:

```
Johns-MacBook-Air:FlaskApp john$ ./app.py 
 * Serving Flask app 'app'
 * Debug mode: on
WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment. Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000
Press CTRL+C to quit
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 908-894-314
127.0.0.1 - - [14/Nov/2022 11:43:39] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [14/Nov/2022 11:43:39] "GET /static/css/bootstrap.min.css HTTP/1.1" 500 -
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/john/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2548, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/Users/john/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2528, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/Users/john/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2525, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/Users/john/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1822, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/Users/john/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/Users/john/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1796, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)
  File "/Users/john/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 713, in <lambda>
    view_func=lambda **kw: self_ref().send_static_file(**kw),  # type: ignore # noqa: B950
  File "/Users/john/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/flask/scaffold.py", line 331, in send_static_file
    return send_from_directory(
  File "/Users/john/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/flask/helpers.py", line 590, in send_from_directory
    return werkzeug.utils.send_from_directory(  # type: ignore[return-value]
  File "/Users/john/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/werkzeug/utils.py", line 591, in send_from_directory
    return send_file(path, environ, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/john/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/werkzeug/utils.py", line 491, in send_file
    file = open(path, "rb")  # type: ignore
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Users/john/Apps/FlaskApp/static/css/bootstrap.min.css'
```

**Python version:** 3.8.2
**Shebang** on app.py file: #! /usr/bin/python3
**Flask version:** Flask 2.2.2, Flask-Ext 0.1

[image: directories structure]

**I have tried the following: **

- Running app with sudo app.py, sudo python3 app.py
- Set all directories and files Permissions to 775 (chmod -R)

**Current behaviour**
Index page for application loads without any CSS and error posted above is thrown

-

Any tips, fixes are greatly appreciated ! Thank you

Comment: What are the permissions on `bootstrap.min.css`? It needs to be readable by the user running the flask server.

Comment: @Barmar. bootstrap.min.css Permissions are 775 (same for all files and directories)

Answer (score 0):

Flask app is now working after setting up venv virtual environment.